Git tab in Rstudio doesn't match Project Directory
I am trying to launch my quarto website from GitHub. I have set up the project and all the website pages via quarto documents, but now that I try to commit the files to the github repository, none of the files in the folder show up in the git tab after ensuring my path in the project options matches my repo. Instead, the git tab holds all files/folders from my system (desktop, documents, etc.), whereas my project in particular is on the desktop.
This is what the git tab looks like:

How can I switch the location of the git tab to include my local project files, in order to commit them?
